# XREF-ing the same table in MySql

Tags: mysql

I need to create a MySql relational DB with the following simple requirements:

- A CLIENT can have many SUBSCRIBERs which themselves are CLIENTs
- A CLIENT can have many CONTACTs which themselves are CLIENTs

It looks like I need two XREF tables, however they are xreferencing the same table (CLIENT)!

So far, the only way I seem to be able to design this is as follows:

[image: xreffing the same table]

Which seems impractical since both CONTACT and SUBSCRIBER are just referencing a CLIENT.

I sense I'm missing something obvious here...

*** EDIT ***

Based on the first comment below, I derived the following simplified table ...

[image: Solution]

Comment: You don't need tables `contact` and `subscriber`. Just make tables `client_contact` and `client_subscriber` reference table `client` twice. In other words make fields `contact_id` and `subscriber_id` foreign keys that reference table `client`.

Comment: Thanks for that Gorges - I updated my question with the revised diagram. Makes sense now - I should have realised that I could reference a table twice. I suppose in a way I was treating the CLIENT table like an instance instead of an object (if that's a valid way of looking at it). Works well now!

Answer (score 0):

You can define your `clients` has many `subscribers` and `contacts` as like -

**TABLE :** `clients`

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+
| id | name        | email                |
+----+-------------+----------------------+
| 1  | A           | email@example.com    |
+----+-------------+----------------------+
```

> **Note :** `id` is the Primary Key

**TABLE :** `subscribers`

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+
| id | client_id   | status               |
+----+-------------+----------------------+
| 1  | 1           | Y                    |
+----+-------------+----------------------+
| 2  | 3           | Y                    |
+----+-------------+----------------------+
```

> **Note :** `id` is the Primary Key and `client_id` is the Foreign Key of `clients` table

**TABLE :** `contacts`

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+
| id | client_id   | status               |
+----+-------------+----------------------+
| 1  | 1           | Y                    |
+----+-------------+----------------------+
| 2  | 3           | Y                    |
+----+-------------+----------------------+
```

> **Note :** `id` is the Primary Key and `client_id` is the Foreign Key of `clients` table

Comment: I think the problem with this is that I can't have duplicate IDs for SUBSCRIBERS and CONTACTS since they are primary key. And I need to have entries like, say for your CONTACTS: 1,1,y - 2,3,y - 2,4,y - 2,5.y

Comment: You can't use duplicate in primary key `id`. It is `auto increment`. You can use duplicate in `client_id` @dbertels

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I need the **combination** of id and client_id to be unique as in an XREF table. My update, inspired by Giorge, works.